# If $x_n\leq y_n$ then $\lim x_n\leq \lim y_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ convergent sequence. Is there an easier way to prove that if $x_n\leq y_n$ for all $n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n\leq \lim_{n\to\infty }y_n$ ?

This is how I do:

Let $\ell=\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n$ and $\ell'=\lim_{n\to\infty }y_n$. Suppose $\ell'<\ell$. Let $\varepsilon=\frac{\ell-\ell'}{2}$. In particular, there is a $N$ such that $y_N\in]\ell'-\varepsilon,\ell'+\varepsilon[$ and $x_N\in]\ell-\varepsilon,\ell+\varepsilon[$ and thus $y_N<x_N$ which is a contradiction with the fact that $x_n\leq y_n$ for all $n$.

I would like to know if there is another proof that doesn't use contradiction.

Comment: $\varepsilon=\frac{\ell-\ell'}{2}$

Comment: @idm If you add the two and then divide by two, you get the midpoint between the two.  That's a pretty big number, so we will get $l \in (l' - \epsilon, l' + \epsilon)$.  We want this interval to exclude $l$.

Comment: @idm So instead we take $\frac{l - l'}{2}$.  Since $l > l'$, $l - l'$ is the *distance* between $l$ and $l'$.  Taking this distance and dividing it by $2$, it follows that $l$ is *not* in $(l' - (\frac{l - l'}{2}), l' + (\frac{l - l'}{2}))$.

Comment: @idm $\varepsilon>0$. how you show that $\frac{\ell+\ell'}{2}>0$

Comment: @idm Similarly, $l'$ is *not* in $(l - (\frac{l - l'}{2}), l + (\frac{l - l'}{2}))$.  That's why $y_{N} < x_{N}$.

Comment: Yes, thanks :-) I was thinking in fact at $$[\ell',\frac{\ell+\ell'}{2}]$$ which is $[\ell',\ell+\frac{\ell-\ell'}{2}]$ as you both said :-)

Comment: Introducing $z_n=y_n-x_n\ge 0$ it is equivalent to prove that $\lim z_n\ge 0$, but the latter is the same as to say that $[0,+\infty)$ is a closed set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A proof without contradiction:

Suppose that $x_n \leq y_n$ for all $n$.  For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that $|x_n - x| \leq \epsilon$ and $|y_n - y| \leq \epsilon$.  We then note that
$$
y - x = (y - y_n) + (y_n - x_n) + (x_n - x) \geq\\
-|y-y_n| + (y_n - x_n) -|x_n - x| >\\
(y_n - x_n) - 2 \epsilon \geq \\
-2 \epsilon
$$
So, we have $y - x > -2 \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.  It follows that $y - x \geq 0$, as desired.

Comment: In this proof, are $x$ and $y$ the limits of $x_n$ and $y_n$ respectively?

Comment: @user21 yes!! Left that out apparently

Comment: That's okay. How do you go from your first line to your third line in the equation? $(y-y_n)+(y_n-x_n)+(x_n-x)\geq-|y-y_n|+(y_n-x_n)-|x_n-x|$? I'm guessing triangle inequality.

Comment: @user21 it's easier than that: $a\geq -|a|$ for any $a\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I understand how you get to $(y_n-x_n)-2\epsilon$...how do you say that that is greater than -2$\epsilon$?

Comment: @user21 note that $y_n\geq x_n$, according to the question statement, and by our supposition

Comment: Actually, I understand that. I'm confused on the next step though. If we know that $\epsilon>0$, then shouldn't $-2\epsilon<0$? Then could we say that $y-x\geq0$?

Comment: @user21 "for **every** $\epsilon>0$." Think about it.

Comment: Hmm....Okay then.

Comment: To prove the last line explicitly I think you need a contradiction Mr. Grossmann!

Comment: @Derek I don’t see why you need a contradiction to prove that the supremum of the set of negative numbers is $0$

Comment: Well when you put it that way...But it all comes down to how one translates statements to other equivalent statements. I feel like in these sorts of proofs dealing with epsilon, many direct proofs are written in a way such that if questioned, the response would be "Because otherwise...", which makes me think contradiction is inherent in the argument. The same can be said for proving the statement in your last comment. Why is $0$ the LEAST upper bound? Because if  one supposed that there was a smaller upper bound, you could find a negative number between that smaller upper bound and $0$.

Comment: If you had no intuition for what supremum meant, then you would have to prove it this way. Otherwise, your proof is relying implicitly on your intuition on what the word supremum represents to you.

Comment: @Derek That's a fair point. At the very least, I have (without contradiction) reduced the problem to the simpler statement that "if $p \in \Bbb R$ is such that $p > q$ for every negative $q$, then $p$ is non-negative."